# Images not displaying the first time in this object program in JS

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas, loading

I am making a battleship game with polar coordinates. After the user chooses two points, a battleship should be drawn in the middle. My Battleship constructor looks like this:

```
function Battleship(size, location, source){
        this.size = size;
        //initializing the image
        this.image = new Image();
        this.image.src = source;
        this.getMiddlePoint = function(){
           //get midpoint of ship
           ...
        }
        this.distanceBetween = function(t1, t2){
           //dist between two points
        }
        this.display = function(){
          var point = [this.radius];
          point.push(this.getMiddlePoint());
          point = polarToReal(point[0], point[1] * Math.PI / 12);
          //now point has canvas coordinates of midpoint
          var width = this.distanceBetween(this.info[0][0], this.info[this.info.length-1][0]);
          var ratio = this.image.width / width;
          ctx.drawImage(this.image, point[0] - width/2, point[1] - this.image.height / ratio / 2, width, this.image.height / ratio);
          //draws the image
        }
      }
```

The `display` method of each ship gets called at a certain point (after the user has chosen the location). For some reason, the images do not show the first time I do this, but when I run this code at the very end:

```
for(var i = 0; i<playerMap.ships.length; i++){
    playerMap.ships[i].display();
}
```

All ships are displayed correctly (not aligned well, but they are displayed). I think there is a problem with loading the images. I am not sure how to fix this. I tried using `image.onload` but I never got that to work. I also tried something like this:

```
var loadImage = function (url, ctx) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = url
  img.onload = function () { 
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

but the same problem kept happening. Please help me fix this problem. [Here](http://msolonko.net/battleship) is the game in its current condition. If you place ships, nothing happens, but after you place 5 (or 10) ships, they suddenly all load.

EDIT:

I solved the problem by globally defining the images. This is still very bad practice, since I wanted this to be in the battleship object. This is my (temporary) solution:

```
 var sub = [];
 for(var i = 1; i<5; i++){
     sub[i] = new Image();
     sub[i].src = "/img/ships/battleship_"+i+".png";
 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are defining all of your methods directly on the instance instead of the prototype? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance. This is not why it's breaking, but just a point about OOP in JS.

Comment: BTW, your little `sub` global array has an empty first element because JS arrays are zero based indexes, e.g. first index is `0`, not 1. I assume you meant to do that to get images battleship_1 through battleship_4, but be aware of that if you loop through that array anywhere else.

Comment: Nice little game though. Good luck with your homework!

Comment: @ChadMoore Thanks for your response! I am aware of the array indexing, and it was intentional. A math teacher wanted me to make this for her algebra class haha. Yes, I'll update my code with prototypes, my bad. I realized that they are more efficient and accepted.